# jquery + prepend text not working

Tags: jquery

I have this following code:

```
$(".preview").find("#panel").each(function(i, val) {
    var x = "" + $(val).html();
    $(x).find(".dmPageHeadline").prepend(" 1 - ");
    console.log($(x).html());
    html += $(x).html();
});
```

This code iterates through all accordion panels, concatenates its content and add " 1 - " to the header ( class "dmPageHeadline" ).
Probably it's a simple detail, but i cannot figure it out... this line

```
$(x).find(".dmPageHeadline").prepend(" 1 - ");
```

doesn't preprend the desired text.

Anyone can point me out what is wrong here?

Thank you very much and happy new year !
Teixeira

Comment: doesn't `#panel` indicate an id? Those can by definition only exist once, so there's no reason to iterate? Are you sure that line is even executed?

Comment: Yes it iterates. The id #panel is autogenerated before for some of my code.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `#panel` and you say you're looping through them...this shouldn't be the case though, an ID **needs to be unique**, otherwise you'll get all sorts of weird or non-existent behavior.

Instead give the elements a `class="panel"` instead of `id="panel"`.  As for the jQuery side, you can simplify it down to:

```
$(".preview .panel .dmPageHeadline").prepend(" 1 - ");​
```

[Here's a working example of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/VFfAV/)

If you wanted the index to climb, then do something like this:

```
$(".preview .panel .dmPageHeadline").each(function(i) {
  $(this).prepend(" " + i + " - "); //maybe (i+1) if you want 1 and not 0 first.
});
```

The [`.prepend()` function](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) can take a string, it's just the way you were prepending that was a little odd :)

Answer (score 1):

It because [`prepend`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#content) expects either HTML, CSS selector, DOM Node or jQuery object. Try this instead:

```
$(x).find(".dmPageHeadline").prepend (document.createTextNode(" 1 - "));
```

Comment: Not working as expected but at least prepends the text. basically i want to iterate through all div ("#panel") inside the accordion and that is working, and for each div("#panel") i would find, i would look for the elements with the class ("dmPageHeadline") and prepend " 1 - " to it but keeping the original html extracted from the div("#panel").